# Why do some hostels only allow international visitors?

Tags: safety, australia, security, hostels

Some of the hostels in the Gold Coast, Australia, only allow international visitors. I'm a bit surprised at this because the average Australian is <s>not at all dangerous</s> only dangerous in the same way your average backpacker is (likely to drink a lot, be an obnoxious idiot, etc.).

Are there some crime or safety reasons for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137765/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-grimm-why-do-some-hostels-only-allow-internatio).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Don't take it personally, that happens in other countries as well.  It's not common, but there are hostels in the US, Canada, and Europe that don't allow people from their own country to stay there.  So if it makes you feel any better, there are U.S. hostels that will happily accept you, but not a U.S. citizen.  I ran into that once myself when I wanted to stay at a hostel here, so I know it is frustrating.

The reasoning is some hostels are trying to create a particular social environment where you can interact with travelers from all different countries.  It's also a way to make sure guests really are people who are traveling, not just locals who need a place to crash, or someone who just arrived in town and is looking for temporary housing.  At worse, some hostels that let anyone stay can end up looking more like a housing project or homeless shelter.

It does solve that problem, but it is unfortunate that they also end up excluding people who really are visiting town from other parts of the country.  I don't think it's a great policy, but that's the reasoning behind it anyway.

Comment: Some hostels have a maximum stay limit to deal with the people who stay a lot longer until they figure out some employment, etc. While it is reasonable for them, it's quite a bad news for real travelers.

Comment: Is there a reason why they're, as a business, turning away customers? Are hostels not for-profit businesses? I wasn't aware they were government-subsidised.

Comment: @NewWorld They are turning away some customers to be more attractive to other customers.

Comment: @NewWorld Who would you rather have in your hostel:  local people who can't afford traditional housing and may accrue tenant rights; or budget minded travelers who can afford international airfare and will be forcibly returned to their home country at government expense (if they overstay their visa)?

Comment: Also, another reason might be that the hostel staff, is not made with locals of that country. I have been to many hostels with people who are good in English but not the local language.

Comment: Just strange you wouldn't solve those problems via some sort of fee you charge for people to stay at the hostel.

Comment: @emory Yet how is it that normal hotels and motels don't worry about tenant rights to the extent that hostels do?

Comment: @NewWorld Some do.  http://articles.latimes.com/2004/jan/25/local/me-warning25  Hence the 28 day shuffle.

Comment: @emory Shuffling customers around rooms is in a whole different ballpark to outright refusing customers business. Having a 28-day maximum booking duration is a trivial solution compared to denying the customer altogether and not making any money.

Comment: I once stayed at a US hostel that required a passport at check-in, but they had no problem when given a US passport.

Comment: Incidentally, it is not lawful in the US for a public accommodation like a hostel to turn people away based on national origin.  You could sue if you really felt like it.

Answer (score 10):

Some places have laws that make it hard and expensive to evict hotel guests who overstay their welcome. International visitors often have to leave the country after a set amount of days, which makes it easy to get rid of them. Unfortunately I do not know if there are any of these "hard to evict" problems in Australia.

Answer (score 5):

Well, That happened to one of my friend. It's true that this happen often. Like the comment above mentioned, some hostels want to have a global social environment rather than bunch of people from the country. I think also the people who use the hotels expect the travelers to be from around the world which create a different environment. Don't be upset but that's the way it is. I travel with 2 passports so I can always find a hostel which accommodate me. I don't frequent them often due to other issues I don't want to discuss. 
In brief, try not to go to a hostel in your own country.

Comment: Most hostels allow visitors from own country and in some kinds of travel hostels are the best option. So if you want to use a hostel, contact them, ask whether they accept you and if not, explain why you need to stay in a hostel in your own country so that if it is not a hard rule they might make an exception.

Answer (score -5):

Many hostels refuse to admit Australians because of their behavior and the way they act, here are some the reasons.

1. Some locals will stop in a backpackers for a few days using fake id and steal
   others personal belongings.
2. Many Aussies who stay in backpackers are transients with dubious criminal back
   or maybe on the run from the law.
3. Locals may try to sell drugs while staying at the premises or hostel.
4. Many hostels refuse to accommodate locals with mental illness.
5. Aussies have a reputation for getting drunk and causing fights.
   having worked in hostels these are the main reasons why Australians are refused service, if your an Aussie wanting to stay in a backpackers turn up well dressed , clean cut and tell them you work. it may or may not work.

Comment: Having been a guest in Ausie hostels, many of which accepted Ausie guests as well, I do not agree with your points.

Comment: People, if you do or do not agree with an answer, voting is the way to express that. This is an answer and of such quality that mods do not need to remove it for lack of quality.

Comment: How are any of these things Aussie specific? *Anyone* can be behave like this. Nevermind #4, which is just an awful thing to state in its own right.

Comment: Can you please add some sources?